# Undo files.split after matching Filename (python 3.x)

Tags: python, split, filenames

Filenames:

File1: `new_data_20100101.csv`
File2: `samples_20100101.csv`

timestamp is always = `%Y%m%d`in the filename after a `_` and before `.csv`

I want to find the files where there is a `data` and a `samples`file and then do something with those files:
My Code so far:

```
for all_files in os.listdir():
    if all_files.__contains__("data_"):
        dataList.append(all_files.split('_')[2])
    if all_files.__contains__("samples_"):
        samplesList.append(all_files.split('_')[1])
```

that gives me the filenames cut down to the `Timestamp` and the extension `.csv`

Now I would like to try something like this

```
for day in dataList:
    if day in sampleList:
         open day as csv.....
```

I get a list of days where both files have timestamps... how can I undo that files.split now so aI can go on working with the files since now I would get an error telling me that for instance `_2010010.csv`does not exist because it's `new_data_2010010.csv`
I'm kinda unsure on how to use the `os.basename` so I would appreciated some advice on the data names.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could instead use the `glob` module to get your list. This allows you to filter just your `CSV` files.

The following script creates two dictionaries with the key for each dictionary being the date portion of your filename and the value holding the whole filename. A list comprehension creates a list of tuples holding each matching pair:

```
import glob
import os

csv_files = glob.glob('*.csv')

data_files = {file.split('_')[2] : file for file in csv_files if 'data_' in file}
sample_files = {file.split('_')[1] : file for file in csv_files if 'samples_' in file}
matching_pairs = [(sample_files[date], file) for date, file in data_files.items() if date in sample_files]

for sample_file, data_file in sorted(matching_pairs):
    print('{} <-> {}'.format(sample_file, data_file))
```

For your two file example, this would display the following:

```
samples_20100101.csv <-> new_data_20100101.csv
```

Comment: that looks interesting I got a problem with `matching_pairs = [(sample_files[date], file) for date, file in data_files.iteritems() if date in sample_files]`     does  `ìteritems` need to be somewhere else as well?

Comment: I have modified the answer slightly as it was designed for Python 2.0. It should now work on Python 3.0.